# Difference between Optional and Nullable filed in Avro Schema

Tags: avro

I am looking for the difference between **Optional and Nullable filed** in Avro Schema.
There is a scenario, where in I don't want the field to be present in the avro message when it is Null. As of now the filed is appearing but with null value.
This is what I have in my schema defined.

```
{
"name": "firstName",
"type": [
"null",
"string"
],
"default": null
}
```

Does avro schema supports suppressing null fields(if value is null, remove the field itself).

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Avro, both the `"nullable"` field and `"optional"` field are treated the same way. This means that when you define a field as [`"null"`, `"string"`], you are saying that the field can either have a string value or null value. The same is true when you say a field is `"optional"`.

based on your current schema definition,

```
{
    "name": "firstName",
    "type": ["null", "string"],
    "default": null
}
```

if you don't provide a value for the field `"firstName"`, it will take the default value as `null`.

Avro itself does not support suppressing or removing fields that are `null` from the serialized data directly in its schema. If a field is defined in the schema, it will be in the serialized data, even if its value is `null`.

If you want to omit fields with `null` values, you would need to handle this logic in your application code, removing the `null` fields before serialization. Another way would be to dynamically generate the Avro schema based on the available fields, excluding fields that have `null` values.

PS: Excluding fields from serialization can make the data incompatible with the original schema. The Avro schema is designed to enforce a specific structure for data, and removing fields could cause deserialization to fail when using the original schema.

Example to filter out null fields before serializing the data using Apache Avro.Let's assume you have a User class, which you are serializing using Avro,

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    
    // getter and setter methods
}
```

You can create a method to remove null fields,

```
public static User removeNullFields(User user) {
    if (user.getName() == null) {
        user.setName(""); // Set to default value if null
    }
    if (user.getAge() == null) {
        user.setAge(0); // Set to default value if null
    }
    
    return user;
}
```

define method before you serialize your User object with Avro.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a User
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(null);
    user.setAge(30);

    // Remove null fields
    User userWithNonNullFields = removeNullFields(user);

    // Now serialize userWithNonNullFields with Avro
    // ...
}
```

This example only works with primitive types like Integer or String where a reasonable default value can be set. If you have more complex types, you may need a more complex method to handle `nulls`.